# Confused about google portfolio chart

Tags: stocks, trading, portfolio, google-finance

I added a test trade using google finance, buying 1 share of Google stock :

[image]

At the end of day here is how the portfolio appears : 
[image]

How the the run percentage so high ? 1367.53% is calculated how ? Stock gained +1.77 so the percentage seems too high. How can I check what value I would gain/lose if I decided to see the shares I own within the portfolio ?

Comment: No, you added a trade of 1 share of GOOG at $67.05, not FB. Fix your data entry error please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bought 1 share of **Google** at **$67.05** while it has a current trading price of **$1204.11**. Now, if you bought a widget for under $70 and it currently sells for over $1200 that is quite the increase, no? Be careful of what prices you enter into a portfolio tool as some people may be able to use options to have a strike price different than the current trading price by a sizable difference.

Take the gain of $1122.06 on an initial cost of **$82.05** for seeing where the 1367% is coming. User error on the portfolio will lead to misleading statistics I think as you meant to put in something else, right?